# Angular Matdialog is missing backdop and theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I'm working an angular app.
I have a quite simple matdialog feature.
But the dialog is not showing the transparent grey overlay backdrop.
My button is not showing primary color neither...

I've been looking for similar issues. Many suggest to add

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Which I did, but not to avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your app?

Comment: @OwenKelvin yes I have tried, but still missing backrdrop and style.